# Selenium - blocking a certain element from appearing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium Firefox web driver for gathering data from a certain web page.
The web page contains sub pages (say, from 1 to 100pg), and I am iterating through them to scrape data. 
But sometimes, the website unexpectedly resets where I am in the paging (if I am on 54th page, I am suddenly back to page 1) by sending a modal pop up.
I am wondering if there is a way to block this sort of behavior - is there a way to block an element from appearing, or block some sort of send signal that would cause this?

Comment: Seems to be website behaviour.

Comment: Is there a way to block this behavior? I think it might be due to a certain POST request. Would it be possible to block that?

Comment: Does this modal popup box appear only once or repeatedly? If only once then there could be a cookie setting which makes the popup appear and once you accept it, does not appear again for the session. If it is a cookie then you need to set it before you begin scraping. Print out the cookies and check them. If you are in control of the site then consult the developers.

Comment: If you can get to the code thats doing it, you can override it via execute_script in WebDriver session.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force application to behave as You want from selenium. I can propose another solution, for example to check if the pop up appeared and close it and then restart the test.